# Contesting a review audit

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

Today I received a month-long review ban that I think is clearly a mistake.  I don't particularly mind a month off of review :), but would like to make sure that the ban process (be it automated or manual) is tuned to be the most effective.

I recommended deletion of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7771529) which I feel is clearly a comment on another answer but was banned for that action.

Previously I have been banned for shorter time periods for actions I consider defendable, but didn't feel it appropriate to contest the ban on the assumption that SO is trying to avoid a long queue of offenders complaining that they were unfairly banned for one reason or another (everyone in prison is innocent :)).  We should all be committed to actions other than arguing over bans. But as user and reviewer of the site I want the review ban algorithm/process to be efficient as well.

---

EDIT: Not particularly relevant to this dispute, but in the interest of full disclosure I'll put the ones I think I failed (based upon lack of reviews for x days afterward) recently.  Clearly I am at odds with all other reviewers for a few of these and will review my review process:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7230683

- 2 recommended deletion (including me); answer deleted

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7331870

- 3 ok (including me), 1 delete; answer deleted

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7353727

- 5 recommend deletion (including me), 1 deleted; answer deleted

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7431215

- 7 recommend deletion, 1 looks ok (me); answer deleted.  IIRC the question asks for a link and the answer was a link

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7476647

- 5 recommend deletion, 1 deleted, 1 looks ok (me); answer deleted

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7510013

- 1 looks ok (me); answer deleted

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought this may be a broader Stack* question but it got  migrated and that's fine with me.

Comment: @eebbesen site specific actions (such as review, closures, bans etc) always be long on the local meta.

Comment: Thank you @psubsee2003 -- noted

Comment: There is something very strange about that entire question.  I see 2, maybe even 3 answers that almost look like comments, but may have a tiny grain of an answer (not familiar enough with iOS to be sure).  I would have done the same as you.  But it really takes a lot to get banned for a month.  Even if you say your position is defensable there just aren't that many band audits to trigger a month long ban.  You really may need to take a look at how you are reviewing,

Comment: Yes, the answers on that question are a mess.

Comment: @psubsee2003 is correct, month means lots of past mistakes as well.

Comment: I'm willing to take responsibility for those poor reviews, but it would be great if I could filter down to the bad ones (I know there are other posts on this topic so I'll refrain here).  Just going by the ones I was told I failed it seems very small, and many of those I would have contested had I realized they would accumulate in this manner because I thought them similarly inaccurate.  In any case, this thread is becoming what I _don't_ want to see on this site (a back and forth over a single user's problems :)) so I'll let it go.  Thanks for your time and comments.

Comment: No, your post is completely appropriate here. This audit is bad and that will be solved, give it some time. You are in the right place to highlight that. Actually, there is no need to argue about your past review history for this particular issue.

Comment: I agree, that was a terrible audit case caused by the "me too" voting we often get around "this service is broken" questions. I've lifted your ban. However, you do need to be a little more careful with your reviews, because you approved these two instances of spam: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7510013 http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7554094 . One was spam for a blog on an old question, the other spam for a product on an off-topic question. Those audit failures triggered the incrementally larger ban.

Comment: Thank you for the lifting of the ban and for the explanation of the reasons behind it @BradLarson.

Answer (score 18):

First the review itself.... I would have done the same as you.  The answer really looks like it is a reply to the other answer and should have been a comment.

The entire question really looks like a mess.  There is at least one more, maybe 2 that are also comments (at least the look like questions with some extra info).  But I don't know enough about iOS to make a solid evaluation as to whether the tiny grains of info are enough for a real answer to the question.

But the whole question and the number of upvotes on everything makes me wonder what is going on in the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag?

---

Now for your ban.  A month long is really tough to get unless you were manually banned by a moderator, and even then it would have to be a serious infraction for a mod to take that step.  And even if it was a manual ban, you would know because the mod would have sent you a message with specific items that they felt you failed on.

So assuming this was an automatic ban, you would have had to fail multiple audits within a 30 day window while also dealing with other bans during that window <sup>(see note below)</sup>.  Even if you say your position on those failed audits is defensible, there is really not that many bad audits out there to fail enough to be banned for a month, even if you were very unlucky.

Given that, when you are able to resume reviewing, I suggest you take a look at how you are reviewing.  Maybe pull up a few audits that you failed from your history and ask about it on meta, or in chat.  I'm sure multiple people would be happy to help you understand why you may have failed those audits and what you can do better.

---

*  - this information is a response to the OP at the time it occurred.  It is no longer accurate as the method for calculating review ban duration changed in 2016.  You can see more about the new method in [Review bans should escalate beyond 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days) and [Is there now a two-month review ban period?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338524/is-there-now-a-two-month-review-ban-period)

Comment: Of the four answers on that question, I think three are comments from people without the ability to comment (at the time) --two are from the same person, accounting for all of their rep.

Comment: @TZHX what it looked like to me - but when you know virtually nothing except what an iphone looks like, it is difficult to make a conclusive statement